# Why ${(\frac{-\sqrt3}2+\frac i2)}^{12}$ in polar form is $cis(10\pi)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

Use DeMoivre’s theorem to find  ${(\frac{-\sqrt3}2+\frac i2)}^{12}$. Express your answer in polar form.

a. 1

b. cis (10π)

c. cis (5π)

d. cis (π)

e. None of these

---

${(\frac{-\sqrt3}2+\frac i2)}^{12}$

Then, I got:

$r=1$

$\theta = 30^{\circ}$

Using DeMoivre’s theorem,

$r^{n}\ cis(\theta) = 1^{12}\ cis\ 30^{\circ} = cis\ \frac{\pi}{6}$

I got $cis\ \frac{\pi}{6}$.

Why the correct answer is $10\pi$?

Comment: $\theta\ne \frac{π}{6}$ but $\frac{5π}{6}$. Notice that $x<0$ and $y>0$.

Comment: I suggest you to write each step explicitly (especially that step from where you found $\theta$) and you will see the mistake.

Comment: Your comment is really helpful @SarGe, thank you very much for your time and comment.

Comment: $1=\text{cis}(10\pi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to include the negative sign on the real part of the complex number. Because it's negative, so the terminal side is in the second quadrant, the angle will be $\pi - \frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{5\pi}{6}.$

Answer (score 2):

You have $\cos(\theta) = -\sqrt{3}/2 < 0$, so $\theta$ is in quadrants II or III, and $\sin(\theta) = 1/2 > 0$, so $\theta$ is in quadrants I or II.  So $\theta$ is in quadrant II, $3\pi/6 < \theta < 6\pi/6$.

You have the correct [reference angle](https://brilliant.org/wiki/reference-angle/), $\pi/6$, but the corresponding angle in quadrant II is $5\pi/6$.